# Why mysql shows foreign key values twice

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, many-to-many, relational-database

I am trying to make etiquette system for my blog. I have created 3 tables for etiquette system. These are etiquetee, content and content_etiquette(there is relation between  content and etiquette). I have tried to set many to many relation between content and etiquettes. There is no problem when I add query to content_etiquette table. But I see values as twice while add attributes on phpmyadmin panel. I have wondered its cause. Is there anyone who know?

[image: phpmyadmin show]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature so that you can start typing either the key or the value in the dropdown. The behavior is configurable, see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ForeignKeyDropdownOrder.

Comment: Are saying that this is not a bug? Thats time I wont change anything.

Comment: Indeed that's not a bug but intended behavior.